# Why is 「の」 used in 何十もの？

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-も

I was studying the words 何十/何百/何千, and I often see the particles「も」and「の」after.

For example,

> 彼は何十冊もの日本に関する本を持っている。

Or,

> 高速道路は何千もの車で渋滞した。

The「も」I think is used to emphasize that there's a large quantity, but what is the purpose of 「の」?

I also found some sentences with a similar pattern, but 「の」 is not used.

Example:

> 彼は何十冊も英語の本を持っている

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is all about grammar and nothing else.

> 「(Number) + **も**」 functions ***adverbially*** to modify a ***verb***.
>
> 「(Number) + **も** + **の**」 functions ***adjectivally*** to modify a ***noun***.

Let us look at your example sentences:

> 「彼{かれ}は何十冊{なんじゅっさつ}**もの**日本{にほん}に関{かん}する本{ほん}を持{も}っている。」

「何十冊**もの**」 modifies the noun 「本」.

> 「高速道路{こうそくどうろ}は何千{なんぜん}**もの**車{くるま}で渋滞{じゅうたい}した。」

「何千もの」 modifies the noun 「車」.

> 「彼は何十冊**も**英語{えいご}の本を持っている。」

In this sentence, 「何十冊も」 modifies the verb phrase 「持っている」.

What would happen if you inserted a 「の」 following the 「も」, then?

In the new sentence:

> 「彼は何十冊**もの**英語の本を持っている。」

「何十冊もの」 will simply modify the noun 「本」 instead.  The meaning of the sentence will virtually stays the same.  The new sentence will just have a different grammatical structure.

EDIT: I did not mention this, but this usage of 「も/もの」 always indicates that the speaker thinks the quantity in question is rather ***large*** as the questioner stated.