# What does 高層ビルに何車線もの道路。mean?

Tags: particle-に, particle-の, particle-も

> 高層ビルに**何車線も**の道路。

I don't understand why they would use the word ''road'' talking about skyscrapers.

I don't entirely get the 何車線も structure either. It reminds me of 何年も but I still can't understand its meaning.

What does that sentence mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56819/9831

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「高層{こうそう}ビル**に**何車線{なんしゃせん}もの道路{どうろ}。」

You clearly are unfamiliar with this use of 「に」.  You are thinking of "at", "in", etc., which is why this phrase makes no sense to you.

This phrase makes perfect sense and it is very natural-sounding.

**「に」 here means "and", "in addition to", etc.**  That usage can be found even in Jisho. See definition #8 in:

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB

Onto 「何車線もの」・・

> 「何{なん} + Counter (or Counter-like Noun) + も + の」

means:

> "Multiple + Counter + も + の"

The nuance here is that the speaker/author feels that the number is rather large (or larger than what one would expect).

When the phrase ends with 「も」, it functions ***adverbially***.

When it ends with 「も + の」, it functions ***adjectivally***.

Putting everything together, the phrase in question means:

> "Skyscrapers and multiple-lane streets"

or

> "In addition to the skyscrapers, (there are also) multiple-lane streets"

Comment: Is there any reason why に was used over と or や ? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: That is difficult to answer without a much longer context.  One possibility, however, is that the author wanted to imply that he could have listed more items than the two to the list.  Using と would make it a complete list with just two items mentioned on it.  や is possible, but it would sound too conversationl.  に is just the best word choice as it implicitly suggests there are more things worth mentioning about this town/area.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why they would use the word ''road'' talking about skyscrapers.

As you list no source, we can only speculate, albeit with a certain level of confidence that (like many a futuristic movie) a roadway cuts through the building, like the story shown [here](https://rocketnews24.com/2011/10/12/138812/).

> I don't entirely get the 何車線も structure either.

も indicates that the speaker considers the frequency/number/etc. of X to be high, likely unexpectedly so. Usually this is done for dramatic effect.
何度も、何回も、何本も、何車線も、these all mean 'several/**many** X', with an emphasis on 'several/many'.
何度か、何回か、何本か、何車線か、these all mean 'a few/**some**/several X', but without any particular emphasis.

Edit: My mention of the roadway cutting through a building was based on search results of the phrase you posted. Upon reflection, @l'électeur 's answer seems more plausible.